# UIColor noColor, but not clearColor

Tags: ios

How can I get the `UIColor` for no color? Y'know, the color represented as a white square with a red diagonal line through it.

**TLDR**
I'm trying to set the tint color of a `UIButton` in interface builder, but it's not playing nice, so I'm trying to do it programatically. If I set the button's tint color to `[UIColor clearColor]`, the button disappears. The button only has an image, no text.

Comment: Did you try setting the color to `nil`?

Comment: TLDR is longer than the rest of the question :-D. Alright, I'm already out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This property not available for all types of UIButton

You need to Use another buttonType.you can find this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006815-CH3-SW39) useful.

the documentation also does not provide information that which specific button types support this property.

so..in general use `custom button type`

Answer (score 1):

Create your button as [custom](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIButton/buttonWithType%3a)...

```
[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom]
```

This will remove your red corner problem since i think your button is created as default (rounded rect) type.

You can set this in interface builder too (not necessarily create it programmatically).